# Can't save a photo captured with standard camera app

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm trying to take a photo with standard camera app and save it to a storage visible only to my app.

```
public void startCamera(View view)
{
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null)
    {
        File imageFile = null;

        try
        {
            imageFile = createImageFile();
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(imageFile != null)
        {
            Uri imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "vasiljevic.filip.secretnotes", imageFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

createImageFile method:

```
private File createImageFile()  throws  IOException
{
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyddMM_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtNoteName);
    String noteName = editText.getText().toString();
    String imageFileName = noteName + "_" + timeStamp;
    File storageDir = new File(getFilesDir(), "images");
    if(!storageDir.exists())
    {
        storageDir.mkdir();
    }

    File image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir);

    return image;
}
```

This is part of the manifest containing FileProvider:

```
<provider
        android:authorities="vasiljevic.filip.secretnotes"
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
    </provider>
```

And file_paths.xml:

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<files-path name="my_images" path="images/"/>
</paths>
```

After I take a photo, it displays the message "camera has stopped" if I run it on the emulator or "gallery has stopped" if I run it on real device. Later if I try to access it with ACTION_VIEW intent it says "can't open image" if I try it on a real device or if I try it on emulator it just behaves as if it had opened an image but the screen is all black and no real image is displayed.

Am I doing it right? is this code supposed to save the image properly? It's mostly based on Taking photos simply official android tutorial: [Taking photos simply](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPath)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION` to the `Intent`. Right now, your third-party app has no rights to save the photo to your `Uri`.

If you are supporting older than Android 5.0, [you might also need to use a `ClipData` workaround](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/08/31/granting-permissions-uri-intent-extra.html), as `Intent` flags do not affect `EXTRA_OUTPUT` on older Android versions.

Comment: Tried it before with that flag and it didn't work, I'm supporting older versions than 5.0 so I'm gonna check this ClipData workaround and see if it works, thanks